# 1 complex addition = 2 real additions, 1 complex multiplication = 4 multiplications + 2 additions.

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Could you show that, when talking about Fourier transforms, that one complex addition requires 2 real additions, and one complex multiplication requires 4 multiplications and 2 additions.

Comment: You can't, because [Gauss discovered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Gauss.27s_complex_multiplication_algorithm) that if you are willing to do 5 additions instead of 2, you can reduce the multiplications from 4 to 3.

Comment: I am not going to read that.

Comment: Why are you not going to read that?

Comment: This comment thread is starting to feel like a Turing test to me....

Comment: Textbook says 'Multiplication involves four individual multiplications ac,ad,bc,bd, one substraction (ac-bd, and one addition ad+bc: (a +jb) x (c+jd) = ac+ j(ad+bc)+ J2bd) = (ac-bd)+j(ad+bc).' Can I say 2 additions instead of 1 addition and 1 substraction?

Answer (score 2):

Given two complex numbers $a+bi$ and $c+di$, one can show that their sum, defined by

$$(a+bi)+(c+di)=(a+c)+(b+d)i,$$

requires two real additions, and that their product, defined by

$$(a+bi)\cdot(c+di)=(a \cdot c-b \cdot d)+(b \cdot c+a \cdot d)i,$$

requires four real multiplications and two real additions (invert the sign of $b \cdot d$ to replace the subtraction by an addition).

However, as both $\textbf{Gauss}$ and $\textbf{MJD}$ have discovered, we can use the commutativity and distributivity properties of real numbers to replace one multiplication by three additions:

$$\begin{align*}(a+bi)\cdot(c+di)&=\Big\{k:=c\cdot(a+b)\Big\}=\Big[k-b\cdot(c+d)\Big]+\Big[k+a\cdot(d-c)\Big]i=\\&=(ac-bd)+(bc+ad)i\end{align*}$$

This approach is useful when some sums can be precomputed; ironically, this is often the case for fast Fourier transforms (why else would you ask?). Nevertheless, while somewhat related, this topic certainly deserves its own question.

Comment: But Wikipedia says "On modern computers a multiply and an add can take about the same time so there may be no speed gain" - "For fast Fourier transforms the complex multiplies involve constant 'twiddle' factors and two of the adds can be precomputed. Only three multiplies and three adds are required" Both method require 6 additions! What's the benefit?

Comment: @user8005 In general, the advantage is negligible, if not non-existent, but there may exist situations where it makes a difference. Operations like [fused multiply–add](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) can also help to speed up a little bit.